# Aging of Data Week Wise in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Here i have a table of task that contains task_id, created_date, completed_date, priority .

I need output that give me the records priority wise and no of week task open .
if completed_date is null than it should calculate the difference from current date.

I need mysql query that return me the record like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|week of created | priority  | Count   |   no of week task open |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|40              | hi        | 20      | 2(week diff of completed |
                                         and create date)
```

Here is the query that give me the data when completed date is exist.

```
select yearweek(created_Date) AS year_week
     , priority, count(*) as cnt
     , yearweek(completed_date) - yearweek(created_date) as Diff 
  from lss_analyseTaskLogView 
 where diffs is not null 
   and diffs <> '' 
   and completed_date is not null 
   and completed_Date <> '0000-00-00' 
 group 
    by Diff
     , priority;
```

Here is the query that give me the data when completed date is not exist.

```
select yearweek(created_Date) as year_week
     , priority
     , count(*) as cnt
     , yearweek(CURRENT_DATE) - yearweek(created_date) as Diff 
  from lss_analyseTaskLogView 
 where diffs is not null 
   and diffs <> '' 
   and (completed_date is null or completed_Date = '0000-00-00 00:00') 
 group 
    by Diff
     , priority;
```

I had combine count of both query when week difference and priority same using query

```
select A.year_week, A.priority, A.cnt + B.cnt As Cnt, A.Diff  from
(select yearweek(created_Date) AS year_week ,priority, count(*) as cnt,
yearweek(completed_date) - yearweek(created_date) as Diff
from lss_analyseTaskLogView
where diffs is not null and diffs <> '' and completed_date is not null
and completed_Date <> '0000-00-00' group by Diff,priority) A,
(select yearweek(created_Date) as year_week,priority, count(*) as cnt,
yearweek(CURRENT_DATE) - yearweek(created_date) as Diff
from lss_analyseTaskLogView
where diffs is not null and diffs <> ''
and (completed_date is null or completed_Date = '0000-00-00 00:00')
group by Diff,priority) B
where A.Diff = B.Diff and A.priority = B.priority and A.year_week = B.year_week;
```

but how can i get record of first two query which are not consider in last query.

how can i get the desire set of record.
suggest me any query regarding my question .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why don't you use "SELECT IF(completed_date IS NULL, yearweek(CURRENT_DATE) - yearweek(created_date), yearweek(completed_date) - yearweek(created_date)) as Diff" instead of two queries?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.